# Fan Always ON (Laptop HP G62)

Tags: 11.10, fan, overheating

Recently, I installed Ubuntu 11.10 on my HP G62. But after I installed i noticed that my laptop fan always ON.

Kindly guide me on how this fix this issue. I'm new to this new lovely O.S.

Thanks!

Comment: Better a higher fan speed than a higher temperature :p Install `lm-sensors`, run `sensors-detect`, choose `yes` at the last step, run `sudo service module-init-tools start`, and give us the output of `sensors`. That should tell us the temperature of your laptop, and in some cases the fan speed as well.

Comment: Hello, welcome to AskUbuntu.com. In order for us to further help you it is necessary that you add more information about your hardware. Please edit your question and add the specific model (all numbers/letters) to it. It will help users reading your question to return to you better answers.

Comment: If the G62 is similar to the G72, the default setting in the BIOS is "fan always on". Have you changed this?

Comment: if its a old (6 to 8 months ) check fan - it needed to be clean , i had g62 few weeks ago ...

Comment: I'm the original poster, but i have the same problem (--i did disable "fan always on" in the bios. Here the outputs: Adapter: Virtual device
temp1:       +59.0°C  (crit = +90.0°C)                  

coretemp-isa-0000
Adapter: ISA adapter
Core 0:      +60.0°C  (high = +80.0°C, crit = +90.0°C)  

coretemp-isa-0002
Adapter: ISA adapter
Core 2:      +56.0°C  (high = +80.0°C, crit = +90.0°C)

Answer (score 2):

As of now, it's better than yesterday.

I just installed **ati-driver-installer-11-12-x86.x86_64.run**

Comment: how did you install it? :